# Restrictions for Principal Bundles on Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I have some manifold $M$ and am wondering what kind of Principal Bundles I am allowed to construct on it.

To be more precise, what are the restrictions when trying to construct principal Bundles over some Manifold? I imagine the topological properties give some quite strict restrictions, but I couldn't find anything in the literature I own.

I am specifically looking for restrictions found on the Torus $T^2$. Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are specifically interested in flat principal $G$-bundles, then there is a one to one correspondance between isomorphism classes of those and $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X, G)/G$. This is achieved by lifting paths horizontally, the flatness of the bundle assures that homotopic loops in $X$ lift to homotopic paths in $P$ with the same endpoint, and the.right action of $G$ (by conjugation) erases the dependency on the origin of those lifts. For general principal bundles, they are classified by homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to the classifying space of $G$.

Comment: As for restrictions, I don't know how to answer you. What do you have in mind? There may be some characteristic classes to consider associated to principal bundles, like (I might be mistaken) Chern-Simons and of course the curvature, so if the cohomology is simple you might get restrictions... I apologize if you know this already ^^

Comment: This might need some fleshing out, but I think $\pi_1X$ (and maybe $\pi_1G$) might be the only obstruction to constructing principal bundles over a surface, if you construct the bundle step by step over a skeleton of the CW structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isomorphism classes of principal $G$-bundles over $T^2$ are labeled by $\pi_1(G)$. Please, see the following [article](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/701838/WSAA_12-1984-2_17.pdf) by:  Klimek-Chudy and Kondracki: "The topology of the Yang-Mills theory over torus", where the isomorphism classes are computed for a few low dimensional base manifolds.

For an alternative method of computation, please see the following two articles by: Yu. A. Kubyshin: [arXiv:math/9911217](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911217): "A classification of fibre bundles over 2-dimensional spaces", and [arXiv:math-ph/0309059](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0309059): "Geometrical formalism in gauge theories".